# Convert display language to subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

For a website I have locally, I need to set the display language as if it were a subfolder, using an htaccess file.
For example, if I choose to display the site in German, instead of displaying it like this => `local_ip/test/index.php?lang=de`, I would like it to be displayed like this => `local_ip/test/de/` .
Also, if I type in the url without setting the language, I would like htaccess to automatically redirect to the German language, from so => `local_ip/test/tour/mountain/` to so => `local_ip/test/de/tour/mountain` .

My current htaccess file is structured as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(.+?)
RewriteRule ^city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&t=%1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&p=%1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(.+?)&p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&t=%1&p=%2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=true
RewriteRule ^city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&c=true [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^city/(.+?)$ city.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tour/(.+?)$ tour.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

**SOLVED**

After several attempts and after reading several support requests posted in this community, I found a way to make the system recognise all the other rules as well. All I had to do was put them before the last rule provided by the user who supported me. Here is the final code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/de/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /test/de/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^de/$ /test/index.php?lang=de [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(.+?)
RewriteRule city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&t=%1&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&p=%1&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(.+?)&p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&t=%1&p=%2&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=true
RewriteRule city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$1&c=true&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteRule city/(.+?)$ city.php?url=$1&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteRule tour/(.+?)$ tour.php?url=$1&lang=de [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What folder is your current htaccess located in?

Comment: In test => local_ip/test/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect URLs to include /de
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/de/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /test/de/$1 [R,L]
# /test/index.php?lang=de to /test/de
RewriteRule ^de/$ /test/index.php?lang=de [END]
RewriteRule ^de/(.+)$ /test/$1 [END]
```

Comment: And if the language is not specified, how can I add it automatically? For example local_ip/test/tour/mountain in local_ip/test/de/tour/mountain

Also, with the code you recommended, if I try to type local_ip/test/de/ the url is converted to local_ip/test/de/index.php?lang=de

Comment: Now it only works if I type local_ip/test. It correctly converts the url to local_ip/test/de/ . But, if I type local_ip/test/about.php it doesn't convert it to local_ip/test/de/about.php .

Comment: @webdevfp Are your php files located inside `/test/` directory?

Comment: Yes, the whole website is placed in /test/

Comment: @webdevfp okay, I did some changes on the code. I commented the first condition and replaced `L` with `END` also added a new rule to handle your other URLs containing /de .

Comment: Excellent! Two more requests: 1) When I move the site online, to the test.com domain, how will I update the .htaccess rules? 2) If I want to add the Italian language and the English language, how should the rules be updated?

Comment: @webdevfp #1) If your directory structure remains the same on the live site then there is no need to do anything , your rule will work without any modification. But if you change your directory structure then you will need to update the directory name in the rule. #2) Please those are different questions . Please ask a new question with that. I would be happy to help you. Thanks

Comment: I tested your code and realised that it no longer loads the CSS files. I tried adding the base tag in the HTML but it doesn't add it.

Comment: @webdevfp did you try `<base href="/test/">` ?

Comment: Yes, I added the <base href="/test/"> tag. But I don't see it in the HTML, it doesn't add it. But if I comment on the rules you recommended, it works, the <base> tag is added correctly.

Comment: Resolved. I had copied your code incorrectly.

Comment: Why did you use [END] instead of [L]?

Comment: @webdevfp `END` is important in your rules to avoid Infinite redirects. If you repace it with `L` then you will get an internal server error (Too many redirects ) .

Comment: Will the other rules I added in my .htaccess work without any updates?

Comment: @webdevfp Yes. These rules are ok and should work. But remember to place this (the code I provided)   just bellow  your `http` to `https` rule

Comment: How can I update this rule (RewriteRule ^de/(.+)$ /test/$1 [END]) to obtain the language via ?lang=de?

Comment: @webdevfp    Just add a default query perameter to the rule's destination `/test/$1?lang=de [END]` and you can then access it with your php

Comment: Good. Thank you very much. I will open a new request for further questions.

Comment: I tried the other rules, they don't work. Could it be that the rule `RewriteRule ^de/(.+)$ /test/$1 [END]` overwrites all the others?